# How to sort titles alphabetically and number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Post model that has many titles. But there is also one main heading that is flagged. Titles contain both text and numbers.

I tried to sort the list of posts as follows:

```
joins(:titles).where(main: true).order('titles.value ASC')
```

Result:

```
abc 1
abc 12
abc 2
bcd 1
bcd 15
bcd 2
```

Sort by text only. Tell me, please, how to do sorting by text (alphabetically), as well as by numbers?

Comment: What is the expected restult?

Comment: @mrzasa Obviously, the number 2 must be up to the number 12. Sort alphabetically and numbers.

Comment: What database do you use? How big is your result set (how many records are returned)?

Comment: @mrzasa postgresql. Approximately 100 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the following code:

```
joins(:titles).where(main: true).order("left(lower(titles.value), 1), substring(titles.value, '\\d+')::int NULLS FIRST, titles.value")
```

It sorts as it should.